# MapView overlaps ListView during double tap zoom

Tags: android, osmdroid

I have problem with osmdroid MapView which overlaps ListView during double tap zoom (and also when I tap plus sign on built in zoom controls).

Here you can see what happens:

[image: MapView problem]

I added into LinearLayout MapView and ListView with `android:layout_weight="1"` and `android:layout_height="fill_parent"`:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:orientation="vertical"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <org.osmdroid.views.MapView
            android:id="@+id/map_view"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1" />

    <ListView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:id="@+id/list_view"
            android:layout_weight="1" />

</LinearLayout>
```

How to solve my problem?